# Повторное выделение кавычками различных названий

Tags: ономастика, пунктуация, названия

Добрый день.
Проконсультируйте кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, по такому вопросу.
Нужно ли выделять кавычками в тексте одно и то же название (например, заведения или организации) более одного раза?

Один знакомый указал мне примерно следующее:
"Названия всего, в том числе организаций и другой неодушевленной фигни, берутся в кавычки при первом их упоминании. Не будет считаться преступлением, если случайно поставишь кавычки повторно. Но лучше не надо."

Реально ли есть какие-то правила на эту тему? Или всё-таки имена собственные, если их нужно выделять кавычками в тексте, то нужно делать это каждый раз?

Answer (score 2):

Нет такого правила. Надо каждый раз. **"Спартак" есть "Спартак". "Спартаку" сильно не везло с тренерами...** И тому подобное.