# Написание собственных имён и постановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация, ономастика

Есть следующий текст:

**Лесные патрули стали называться зелёными патрулями а их члены зелёными шерифами.**

Вопросы:

- Как правильно расставить знаки пунктуации в данном предложении?
- Как правильно написать собственные имена в данном предложении: «Зелёными патрулями», «Зелёными Патрулями», «Зелёными шерифами», «Зелёными Шерифами»?

Если словосочетания «Зелёными патрулями» и «Зелёными Шерифами» являются собственными именами, которые в данном предложении выделяются кавычками, возможно ли, дальше по тексту, использование этих собственных имён без кавычек?

Пример: 
Зелёные патрули вышли на патрулирование. 
В группу Зелёных Шерифов попасть не легко

Answer (score 1):

Экологический словарь дает название *Зелёный патруль* с заглавной буквы и без кавычек (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ecolog/3795/%D0%97%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%81%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99). Про этом указывает, что члены Зелёного патруля называются дозорными (а не шерифами).

Покольку в тексте вводится и объясняется термин *зеленый шериф*, то я думаю, это словосочетание можно писать без кавычек, а по аналогии с простыми шерифами — строчными буквами.

**Лесные патрули стали называться Зелёными патрулями, а их члены — зелёными шерифами.**

И далее везде в том же тексте можно употреблять эти два термина в том же виде.

Запятая, как обычно, ставится перед союзом *а*, а тире во втором предложении я поставил вместо опущенных слов "стали называться" (но это тире не обязательно).

P.S. Ваш второй пример ("В группу Зелёных Шерифов попасть нелегко.") неудачен. Он был бы уместен, если бы речь шла о некоторой отдельной группе под названием "Зелёные шерифы". Корректно: "В зеленые шерифы попасть нелегко." (Аналогично: "В пионеры попасть нелегко.")

P.P.S. Ответ на вопрос, можно ли "закавыченное" название писать без кавычек при повторном употреблении, — отрицательный (см. [Повторное выделение кавычками различных названий](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417864/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9))

Answer (score 0):

Перед союзом "а" нужна запятая.

**Лесные патрули стали называться зелёными патрулями, а их члены зелёными шерифами.**

По поводу строчной/прописной.

Прозвища пишутся без кавычек и с прописной. Например: **Владимир Красное Солнышко, Ричард Львиное Сердце. Ср.: служанка по прозвищу Великий Могол.**

Однако в вашем примере возможно двоякое понимание. Если рассматривать составное наименование как часть имени, тогда обе буквы должны быть прописные. Если составное наименование -это имя нарицательное,  сопровождающее собственное имя  **(ср.: Мороз-воевода, Иван-царевич, Мышка-норушка),** тогда с заглавной пишется только первое слово.